# How do I install the latest Caliburn Alpha for a new VS Solution?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am trying to write a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro but want to start with the 4.0.62-alpha version (I know it is alpha, by time I am ready the Beta will be out) If I install 3.0.2 I can't upgrade to 4.0.62alpha for Core and Micro, if I on;y install 4.0.6.2-alpha then the Bootstrapper is missing.

I tried installing just the -alpha Micro and .Core, also tried installing 3.0.2 and replacing .Core and .Micro. All were blocked due to conflicting dependencies.

Can I only install the -alpha from source code?